# Removing all panels from AnythingSlider and re-starting plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I'm using the AnythingSlider to display a mashup of tweets, blog posts, flickr photos, and youtube videos, and initially it works great.  I'm trying to add sort functionality, but to do so I need to remove all slides on a button click -> add the new slides -> and re-initialize the plugin.

The AnythingSlider documentation (as well as the code) hints at the ability to remove slides and the plugin should just take it in stride.  I haven't been able to find any kind of remove code anywhere, so I fiugured something like this would work:

```
$("#slider li:not(.cloned)").remove();
```

but so far i've had no luck.  Anyone have any experience with something like this?  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in code to remove slides, so you could use the code above, or if you really want to just remove all the slides, do this (no need to avoid removing the cloned slides):

```
$('#slider li').remove();
```

Then add in whatever new slides you want (sorted or whatever)

```
$('<li>New Stuff</li>').appendTo('#slider');
```

Then update the slider

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider(); // don't include options
```

The above code is essentially the same code as see on the [AnythingSlider demo page](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/) (the buttons next to the theme selector). I've included it below with more comments :)

```
// Add a slide
var imageNumber = 1;
$('button.add').click(function(){
  $('#slider1')
    // add a new slide, but cycle between two images
    .append('<li><img src="images/slide-tele-' + (++imageNumber%2 + 1)  + '.jpg" alt="" /></li>')
    // update the slider
    .anythingSlider();
});
$('button.remove').click(function(){
  // don't let the last slide get deleted - it's ok if you do delete it, it's just not purdy ;)
  if ($('#slider1').data('AnythingSlider').pages > 1) {
    // remove the last slide (the cloned slide is actually the last, that's why there is a ":not()" in there
    $('#slider1 > li:not(.cloned):last').remove();
    // update the slider
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
  }
});
```